# Selecting field from array based on a value filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

Very new to Angular (and the whole MEAN stack).

I have a MongoDB db collection as so:

```
db.users({ 
    username: "Test1", 
    fname: "Bob", 
    lname: "Saget", 
    email: "test@test.com", 
    password: "12345",  
    status: [{ 
        active: false, 
        "non-active": false, 
        suspended: true, 
        "un-confirmed": false, 
        banned: false 
    }] 
})
```

I'm simply wishing to print all users to the screen. And have been doing it with success, like so.

```
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>{{user.username}}</td>
            <td>{{user.fname + ' ' + user.lname}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            <td>{{user.password}}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
```

My problem comes with trying to display the field (not the value) of the status array based on the boolean value. So in the example it would read 'suspended' one the page rather than 'true' (and only bring back the true values - to which there will only be one).

Have I become cross-eyed, is there a better db structure to adhere too for this type of functionality?

I've tried combinations of ng-if, and ng-repeat with filter: {} options.

I can provide extra details if needed.

How would you guys go about this?

Many Thanks

Comment: angular.forEach loop would do after getting the users from the DB. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: Edward, would I be be putting the logic of the forEach into my controller logic rather than the html page like I've done already above in the ng-repeat part?

Comment: Yeah of course, so after you make the $http to get the users, you would iter over your users and by doing so get the key/value and set the value inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the users you can go through them and update the status like this.

```
angular.forEach($scope.users, function(a, b){
  var user = a;
  var status = a.status[0]; // <-- because your status are an array we pick the first one.
  for (var k in status) {
    if (status.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      if (status[k]) { // <-- if status is true then get the key.
        user.status = k; // <-- set the user status object to the key.
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You can change `user.status = k` to whatever you wish, setting it to status overwrites the status array.

Working example -> http://jsbin.com/zarulo/1/edit?html,js,output

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this didn't exactly solve my problem (it was my own explanation that lacked clarity) You're post has helped me overcome the problem anyway. Thanks for the time and effort. I am using most of the code you posted.